# Synchronization issue with QStateMachine

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, state-machine

I have an instance of a `QStateMachine` in my program. I configure it's states,  transitions, and initial state in it's constructor. And of course, I start it in the constructor.

```
this->stateA = new StateA(this);
this->stateB = new StateB(this);
this->stateA->addTransition(this, &Machine::foo, this->stateB);
this->setInitialState(this->stateA);
this->start();
// At this point the machine is still not in the stateA
```

The issue I faced, was that the machine does not move to an initial state before `start()` finishes execution. This results in a problem that a signal `foo`, which is supposed to move the machine from the initial state to another one, is emitted before the initial state was entered.

```
Machine* machine = new Machine(); 
// start() was already called here but the machine is still not in the initial state
machine->foo();
// Signal is emitted here (It also may not be emitted. This is not an unconditional transition). But the machine is still not in the initial state and the transition does not happen.
// ...
// Here the machine enters the initial state...
```

How can I make sure the machine is in the initial state at the point of its construction?

Answer (score 0):

State machines are asynchronous, and are driven by the event loop. There is no reason for you to use the signal to move the machine to another state on startup. As it stands, you want to transition from `stateA` to `stateB` on startup *and* whenever `foo` is emitted.

1. Remember that the target of a connection can be either a signal or a slot. You can connect the state machine's `started` signal to the `foo` signal. This way, `foo` will be emitted when the machine has started and is in the initial state.
2. If you don't care for the `foo` signal otherwise, you can set up the transition to trigger directly on the machine's `started` signal.
3. If you *always* want to transition from `stateA` to `stateB`, even some time after the machine was started and `stateA` is somehow reentered, you can ad an unconditional transition from initial state to `stateB`. The machine, upon entering `stateA`, will leave it, then enter `stateB`, automatically.

Examine the solutions starting from the last one, and move up if you need a less general solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I probably did not describe what I wanted to achieve well. I do not want to always perform the transition from `A` to `B` on the machine startup. `machine->foo()` may or may not emit the signal depending on some conditions. I want the transition to be performed only after the signal.

Comment: As far as I can see the only workaround is to wait until the machine enters the initial state (to wait for an `initialized` signal from it) and only after that to perform any operations on it.

Comment: @Kolyunya It's not a workaround, it's what you should have been doing all along. Think asynchronously. Don't "wait" until the machine starts, merely run some code *when* it starts. This is done by connecting the `started` signal to a slot, or to a functor.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that the machine is in it's initial state at the point of it's construction by creating an event loop in the constructor like this:

```
// ...
this->start();
QEventLoop* eventLoop = new QEventLoop(this);
QObject::connect(
    this, &Machine::started,
    eventLoop, &QEventLoop::quit
);
eventLoop->exec();
```